# Is it possible to require removal of attribution under BY-SA for distributions not yet created?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, creative-commons, attribution

[CC BY-SA 4.0 §3(a)(3)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode#s3a3) requires that attribution of licensed material be removed if the licensor requests it.

As the licensor, is it possible to make this request *in advance of* the redistribution of licensed material? For example, if I don't like the manner in which X is using my work, can I ask them to remove any attribution to me they have provided on existing redistributions, but *also* on any redistributions of my work that they may provide in the future (without either party knowing what they might be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

The licence allows you to request you not be attributed “to the extent reasonable practicable.” It is reasonably practical for you not to be attributed on distributions that have not yet happened.

Comment: The exact wording is "If requested by the Licensor, You must remove any of the information required by Section 3(a)(1)(A) to the extent reasonably practicable." It seems to me that "reasonably practicable" is applying to the licensor removing information, rather than to the licensee's request for non-attribution - i.e. if removing some information is impracticable _for this request_, it can be skipped. I can't see that it necessarily implies future cases too?

Comment: @ArtOfCode the clause has no temporality in it - it applies equally to the past, the present and the future.